# Использование IF со style.backgroundImage

Tags: javascript, jquery, if, background

Привет. Я начал изучать JS и в процессе работы возник вопрос.

Я вызываю простую функцию, которая проверяет фоновое изображение div с id #play-edm-track, который по умолчанию имеет фон "img/portfolio/play-hover.png". После этого я хочу заменить фон на другой. Однако по какой-то причине утверждение IF ложно.

```
function() {
if (document.getElementById('play-edm-track-1').style.backgroundImage == "url(img/portfolio/play-hover.png)") {
    document.getElementById('play-edm-track-1').style.backgroundImage = "url(img/portfolio/play-inactive.png)";
}
};
```

Как реализовать эту задачу? Можно ли это сделать средствами JS или нужно обязательно использовать jQuery? Спасибо.

Comment: Что в консоле выдает - `console.log(document.getElementById('play-edm-track-1').style.backgroundImage)`?

Comment: По какой-то причине функция

function() {
 console.log(document.getElementById('play-edm-track-1').styl‌​e.backgroundImage);
};

не работает. Если вывести через alert:

function() {
 alert(document.getElementById('play-edm-track-1').style.backgroundImage);
};

то во всплывающем окне высвечивается url("img/portfolio/pause.png")

Answer (score 0):

Если background-image не задан элементу "инлайном" (т.е. не прописан в теге самого элемента), то `.styl‌​e.backgroundImage` выдаст "пустое" значение. Если нужно прочитать это значение из стилей, то тогда нужно использовать:

```js
let block = document.getElementById('Block');

//Получаем значение стиля 
let bg = window.getComputedStyle(block).getPropertyValue('background-image');

//Т.к. значение возвращается в виде строки url(...), убираем ненужные для проверки символы и получаем "чистую" ссылку на изображение
let bg_clear_url = bg.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "")

//После чего делаем проверку
if(bg_clear_url === 'https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/38/2/1505774813-photo4.jpg') {
 console.log('true')
}
```

```css
div {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 border: 1p xolid #c0c0c0;
 background-image: url(https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/38/2/1505774813-photo4.jpg);
 margin: 30px auto;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="Block"></div>
```

Comment: Хорошо, конечно, что вы ответили на вопрос. Но зачем отвечать на вопрос, который заведомо поведет вопрошающего не в ту сторону? Может, лучше показать, как надо правильней сделать.

Comment: я всегда открыт к диалогу и более детальному обсуждению ответа к вопросу.

Comment: В реально проекте вы бы стали использовать сравнение с `url`, для его последующего изменения? Мне кажется, надо улучшить ваш ответ, где указать более правильный путь, например, через атрибуты элемента.